# Is it possible to group by first characters of a column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate

So I have the following table:

```
Name    Value
A          10
ABC         5
A           8
ABC         3
AB          2
```

And I want this result:

```
Name    Value
A          28    
AB         10    
ABC         8
```

So I don't want to group by exact match with Name, but by the starting characters. Is it possible?

Comment: I'd like to see more data.  If your data had an `ABD` value, would the `AB` be grouped with `ABC` or `ABD`?

Comment: Hello, with both of them. Then AB's group shall contain ABC and ABD values also.

Comment: Please mark your RDBMS version

Comment: Does this recurse through strings of 4 - n characters also ie grouping on first 3 chars, then 4 chars etc?

Comment: Only 3 charachter and always in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query differs depending on whether or not the result includes `non-existent character data` (e.g. "B" does not exist for "BC").

If you use a recursive query, the result contains `non-existent character data`.

```sql
WITH cte as (
  SELECT SUBSTRING(Name,1,3) Name, SUM(Value) Value FROM Table1
  GROUP BY SUBSTRING(Name,1,3)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTRING(Name,1,LEN(Name)-1), Value FROM cte
  WHERE LEN(Name)>1
)
SELECT Name, SUM(Value) FROM cte
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name
```

If you use subqueries joined, the result doesn't contain `non-existent character data`.

```sql
WITH cte as (
  SELECT SUBSTRING(Name,1,3) Name, SUM(Value) Value FROM Table1
  GROUP BY SUBSTRING(Name,1,3)
)
SELECT
  t1.Name,
  SUM(t2.Value)
FROM cte t1 JOIN cte t2
  ON t1.Name=SUBSTRING(t2.Name,1,LEN(t1.Name))
GROUP BY t1.Name
ORDER BY t1.Name
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZuK4PHG_)

Example with more data: [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5xhO9BWG)

If `Name` is 3 characters, `SUBSTRING(Name,1,3)` is just `Name`.
See the following.

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fe8iL0Vx)

Example with more data: [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/N1TFZ7OZ)

Comment: the demands says that's only for the 3 first characters, not the complete lenght of the string... vote -1

Comment: The OP has [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74588595/is-it-possible-to-group-by-first-characters-of-a-column-in-sql/74589011?noredirect=1#comment131660803_74588595) that it will only beup to 3 characters, @SQLpro .

Comment: @larnu He his confirmed that the calculus will be done only for 3 characters by never says that all the strings are 3 char length... If he will respects the posting rules by giving the DDL of the table, we can see if this column is a CHAR(3)...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UNION` for each number of characters you want to group by. Something like this:

```
SELECT cat, SUM(val) num FROM (
  SELECT SUBSTRING(Name,1,1) cat, SUM(Value) val FROM table GROUP BY cat
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTRING(Name,1,2) cat, IF(LENGTH(Name)>1, SUM(Value), 0) val FROM table GROUP BY cat
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTRING(Name,1,3) cat, IF(LENGTH(Name)>2, SUM(Value), 0) val FROM table GROUP BY cat
) a
GROUP BY cat
ORDER BY cat
```

The `IF`-operator on the string length prevents inclusion of sums for strings shorter than the length you want to calculate on.

**Result**

```
+──────+─────+
| cat  | num |
+──────+─────+
| A    | 28  |
| AB   | 10  |
| ABC  | 8   |
+──────+─────+
```

Comment: @Michael_Krikorev For performances reason, you should use UNION ALL instead of UNION.... Vote -1

Comment: @SQLpro thanks for the feedback. The results should be the same. I have updated the answer with `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`

Answer (score -2):

With SQL Server 2022 :

```
SELECT LEFT("Name", "value") AS STRING, SUM("Value") AS TOTAL
FROM   SoIHaveTheFollowingTable
       CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(1, CASE WHEN LEN("Name") > 3 THEN 3 ELSE LEN("Name") END)
GROUP  BY LEFT("Name", "value")
ORDER BY STRING;
```

NOTE : with a case senitive database collation because of the two columns nammed "Value" and "value"... By the fact you should never use SQL identifiers that are reserved words (value, name, type, date...)

For version < 2022, use a recursive query first to generate the serie of int values

Comment: Why use a recursive query on 2019 or prior and not just a simple tally? The OP only has strings of up to 3 characters, according to the comments, so adding recursion would be a significant overhead for something that really doesn't need it.

Comment: Also, rather than guessing the OP is on a case sensitive collation (which I would guess is unlikely), you should really be using aliases and qualifying your columns.

Comment: @larnu Because Rob Don does not respect the posting rules by not giving DDL of the tables...

Comment: I'm not sure why a lack of DDL is a reason to use a slower solution or is a reason to not qualify your objects, @SQLPro . As a SQL Pro, you should know the importance of aliases and qualifying.

Comment: @larnu Slower ? Do you think that BINARIES collations are slower ? I constantly prove the opposite in my courses for professional  and in engineer schools...

Comment: I *know* recursion is slower than a set-based, @SQLPro .